# Why is Eclipse PDT marking these lines as errors?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Eclipse PDT is marking two lines as errors. My website running fine without errors in a browser, but the red "x" in Eclipse is bugging me. Here are the two lines:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="<?php echo HOME ?>css/xsl/template.xsl" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php echo HOME ?>css/xsl/style.css" ?>
```

I already have short tags disabled, so I don't know why it's still consider an error.

Btw, the error message is:

> Processing instruction not closed.

**Edit:** I changed the two lines to make PHP echo the lines instead. This solves the problem, but I still want to know why this is occurring. I'll wait a day or two for new answers before selecting a correct answer.

Comment: Just a guess, but you have (technically) a processing instruction (PHP) inside an XML attribute. I don't know if that's "allowed".

Comment: Is the file a `.php` file? (I'd assume so) What if you use shorttags? (`<?= HOME ?>`)

Comment: The shorttag caused a PHP error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "Use Short Tags" checkbox in the "PHP > PHP Interpreter" section of the Eclipse Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug in he parser. I guess the red marker goes away if you remove `<?php echo HOME ?>`. If this is true, you may ignore this problem.